# Will Antonio Valencia get suspensions after being sent off in a friendly match?

Tags: football, suspension

Usually in a competitive football match, a player will get suspensions after getting a red card.

But the match between Manchester United and Real Salt Lake City is a friendly match, I was wondering if he'll get suspensions too. And, is there any examples of a player getting suspensions after being sent off in a friendly match?

Comment: Actually, in competitive matches, a player will *always* get suspensions after getting a red card. There are no exceptions. For a player to escape suspensions, the red card would need to be over-ruled by a tribunal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [manchestereveningnews](http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/sport/football/transfer-news/man-utd-news-antonio-valencia-13346246) article states that **Valencia will not serve a suspension for his red card**. With the help of same article,

*Wayne Rooney and Paul Scholes served three-match ban for being sent off in a pre-season tournament in Amsterdam 3-1 win over FC Porto*. [[Source]](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2006/aug/16/newsstory.sport2)

Comment: He's included in the starting 11 list on Manchester Derby in Houston now :)